# Background Image not stretch to cover tablet Height

Tags: html, css

I have a large enough background image for my site but when I see it using my table the image does not cover the entire screen. You can see the grey background (generated by browser i assume) at the bottom. Also, if i expand articles on my page, the height increases but not the image it goes to the center

This is the site im testing: http://www3.carleton.ca/clubs/sissa/html5/

CSS:

```
body{
    width: 100%; /*always specify this when using flexBox*/ 
    height:100%;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -moz-box;
    display: box;
    text-align:center;
    -webkit-box-pack:center; /*way of centering the website*/
    -moz-box-pack:center;
    box-pack:center;
    background:url('images/bg/bg14.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 13px;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Can you add a link to the website? Or add the rest of your CSS/HTML?

Comment: Sorry forgot: http://www3.carleton.ca/clubs/sissa/html5/

Comment: My FireFox, Chrome, and Safari look fine. Did you fix your issue?

Comment: Are you using a mobile device? I added 100% size like the answer below suggested. I'm trying now on my Nexus 7 and it looks the same as the image above. May be a cache issue though.

Comment: Yea I still get the same issue after clearing the cache. I Chrome (desktop) the rule background-size: 100% gets ignored when i inspect elements. So I'm not sure if the same thing is happening on the tablet side of things

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved this issue by changing rule `-webkit-background-size: cover` to `-webkit-background-size: cover !important`

Seems to work thus far.

Comment: Only if something else is overwriting it.

Answer (score 0):

I've had more success using percentages with `background-size`.

```
element {
  background:url(xyz.jpg) no-repeat center center;
  background-size:100% 100%;
  /* OR */
  background-size:100% auto;
  /* OR */
  background-size:auto 100%;
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't the background-size: cover; rule do the same thing? I'n Chrome (desktop) none of the background-size rules are being applied when I inspect elements.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution by putting a height and width on the HTML.  The other solutions wouldn't make the background fill the screen on my Nexus 10.

```
html { 
    background: url(backgroundImg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
```

If I hit problems on an iPad, then I'll try adding back in the !important on those.  Just want to see if I can go without.